# (inter portlet communication) IPC in liferay 6.0.5 and JSF1.2

Tags: jsf, portlet, liferay, liferay-6

We are trying to implement a portlet communication that will be able to simulate the classical redirect, but without success for now.

This looks to be a common question in the portlet world, but there is a lack of documentation/howtos/tutorials on specific portal implementations.

Does anyone have a positive experience achieving portlet communication in this environment:
 - liferay 6.0.5
 - JSF1.2 - richfaces 3.3.x implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPC Public render parameters get passed to other portlets in the RENDER phase, IPC events get sent in the ACTION phase and passed to the other portlets in the EVENT phase. If you use JSF and don't reload the page then neither of these are possible so Portlet communication via IPC is not an option.

It is however possible to have them communicate using Javascript purely on the client side. The responsible way to manage this is to get each JS library to use the portlet namespace to prevent method and variable collision, but in a controlled environment (ie when you write all custom portlets running on the Portal server) you can omit this.

The other way is to have all communicating portlets to use the Portal server as a middleware container, and they all have to write data to the server and get updates by polling the server. This is not as clean or easy as talking JS to each other directly on the client.